# Why can't I run an application or console from within Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, execute, external-application

I am trying to update a 200,000 line program written in Java/Eclipse in 2009.

I imported it to the latest Eclipse/Java, and there are several problems:

1. the following line (which ran inn 2009) generates an error message

   ```
    try 
    {
        consoleProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console");
     } 
     catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
     }
   ```

The error message is "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)"

However, the file is definitely there, it shows up in the finder (although not in an "ls" command from a terminal window, which I'd also like to get input on.) and I can click on it and run it. I also cannot run BBEdit this way :  I can however run  open/run XQuartz using similar code.

I started trying to write around this problem by trying to open a console with the following  code, which however produces the error message that "The console is NULL"

```
import java.io.Console;



    Console console = System.console();
    if(console == null) {
        System.out.println("The console is NULL");
    }        
    else 
    {
        String  ch=console.readLine();    
    }
```

Thanks so much !!

Comment: Don't trust Finder to check what file really exists on the filesystem, it lies

Answer (score 1):

Use the macOS `open` command to run an application:

```
open -a Console
```

You can't find Console using the `ls` command in `/Applications` because Finder is actually showing the contents of `/Applications` merged with `/System/Applications`. The path to Console is actually:

```
/System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console
```

This split was introduced in macOS Catalina.

Note: `System.console()` is something else entirely, it isn't available in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks so much !!   Any idea where might I have found this documented ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where this is documented, I just remember seeing it in a "whats new" article. Everything that should not be changed was moved to the read only `/System` file system. Finder often doesn't show exactly what is in the file system. Command line utilities such as `ls` are more reliable for that.